# Combining BlockingQueues or BlockingQueue with item retrieval logic

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I need an instance of `BlockingQueue` for `ThreadPoolExecutor` but with a twist.

Let's say we have items of class A and class B in our queue. I have to be able to tell this queue which class (A, B, or both) should be used when asked. `PriorityBlockingQueue` is not the way, because I should be able to control it any time, not only upon creation.

I guess it can be implemented either by writing my own implementation of `BlockingQueue` or by combining two `BlockingQueue`s in some way.

All suggestions are welcome.